# SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 how to solve it

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, error-handling

i was making a news website and got this error.

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

how to solve it?

```js
function getnews(){
    fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?q=india&apiKey=f4176dc9b5194205b4ea64370c715b9b',{headers: new Headers({"X-Requested-With":"hgsofuvuwaoao"})})
    .then(a => a.json()).then((response) =>{
console.log(response);
    })
}
getnews();
```

Comment: `a => a.json()` this is causing the issue, the API call is returning an Html error page, which it can't parse like JSON, so you are getting this error, add a failsafe condition

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are requesting from the correct URL?

```
https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?q=india&apiKey=f4176dc9b5194205b4ea64370c715b9b
```

looks like two URLs to me. If you enter it "raw" as you did you get a html site saying: `Missing required request header. Must specify one of: origin,x-requested-with`.

The Json data is at

```
https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?q=india&apiKey=f4176dc9b5194205b4ea64370c715b9b
```

Since it is trying to parse html it reads the `<` of the html tags and throws an error there. Try changing the URL and look if that fixes it.

The raw data at the URL you provide is

```
<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" href="resource://content-accessible/plaintext.css"></head><body><pre>Missing required request header. Must specify one of: origin,x-requested-with</pre></body></html>
```

which understandably isn't a valid json format.

Comment: thank you sir i edited the url from http to and https this worked for me thank you so much

Comment: No problem, I am glad I could be of help.

Comment: hello sir it is again showing this error while i corrected the url

Comment: Can you paste exactly what URL you are requesting at the moment?